# How can I get only these rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV with a structure as follows:

| Index | GUID | Vector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 36099 | b770 | [-0.04870541 -0.02133574 0.03180726] |
| 36098 | 808f | [ 0.0732905 -0.05331331 0.06378368] |
| 36097 | b111 | nan |
| 36096 | b6b5 | [0.025697 -0.08277534 -0.0124591] |
| 36083 | 9b07 | [ 0.025697 -0.08277534 -0.0124591] |

I load the CSV into a padas dataframe. Now I want to remove the rows having nan in the column Vector.

I have tried with commands as follows:

`user_df=user_df[user_df['Portrait_Job'].str.contains("[nan]")]`

However, it does not work, perhaps, the [nan] is a form of vector but have nan inside.

Could you pls help me to solve this issue

Thank you!

Comment: try with replace `user_df.replace("[nan]",float('NaN'),regex=true).dropna()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.dropna()` to remove each row include `nan` value:

```py
user_df.dropna(subset=['Vector'],inplace=True)
```

Which in `subset` you should specify which column you want to include.

Comment: won't `inplace=True` leave the row? This isn't what OP asked for, right?

Comment: ```inplace=True``` do same as df=df.dropna() no more